# Chromeium Web audi api copyToChannel undefined

Tags: google-chrome, udp, buffer, web-audio-api, audiobuffer

I get AudioBuffers from the node.js speakers module and want them to get played via the web audi api in chromeium (node webkit). So my problem is that I have to get one channel ( as a buffer) and send it via UDP to my client. This client then wants to play it, but chromeium has not yet implemented the method "myArrayBuffer.copyFromChannel(anotherArray,1,0);".

This Method would solve my Problem perfectly but its undefined.
Is there any workaround.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

getChannelData() and set() (from TypedArray)?

Comment: Thanks but I get a buffer from my UDP socket, how can I cast this to a Float32Array. I cant get this work.

Comment: If your buffer is just an Array, you might have to copy the data.